# Does Maven have its own build system. meaning can build project without Ant?

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have see a lot of doc that Maven can read Ant xml file, Does this mean Maven empoly Ant to build project ?

Comment: out of curiosity: Do you have any links to documentation claiming this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Maven is standalone. It has a completely separate dependency engine. It *does* have an [Ant plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/), which allows it to make use of Ant tasks, but it's not mandatory.

> This plugin provides the ability to run Ant tasks from within Maven.
>   You can even embed your Ant scripts in the POM!
>
> It is not the intention of this plugin to provide a means of polluting
>   the POM, so it's encouraged to move all your Ant tasks to a build.xml
>   file and just call it from the POM using Ant's  task.
>
> One of the main purposes of this plugin is to facilitate the migration
>   from Ant based projects to Maven. Some projects may not currently be
>   able to migrate because they depend on custom build functionality that
>   Maven doesn't provide by default.

Answer (score 0):

there's a plugin for that

> This plugin provides the ability to run Ant tasks from within Maven. You can even embed your Ant scripts in the POM!

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/